# Limit involving singular kernel: $\lim_{s\to 1}(1-s)\int_{\Omega}\frac{(u(x)-u(y))}{|x-y|^{d+2s}} d y. $

Tags: integral-operators, integral-geometry, euclidean-domain, singular-support

Let $\Omega\subset \Bbb R^d$ be a bounded  $C^1$ domain. Let $u:\Bbb R^d\to \Bbb R$ be a function in $C^2_b(\Bbb R^d)$. I would like to compute the following limit: for $x\in \partial \Omega$

$$L= \lim_{s\to 1}(1-s)\int_{\Omega}\frac{(u(x)-u(y))}{|x-y|^{d+2s}} d y. $$

Here is what I did so far:

Let $r>0$ be arbitrarily small enough. Then as $u$ is bounded, we have

$$\begin{align}&\lim_{s\to 1}(1-s)\int_{\Omega\cap \{|x-y|\geq r\}}\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^{d+2s}}dy\\&\leq C \lim_{s\to 1}(1-s)\int_{|x-y|\geq r}\frac{dy}{|x-y|^{d+2s}} \\&= Cc_d\lim_{s\to 1}(1-s) \int_r^\infty t^{-2s-1} dt= 0. \end{align}$$

so that

$$L= \lim_{s\to 1}(1-s)\int_{\Omega \cap B_r(x)}\frac{(u(x)-u(y))}{|x-y|^{d+2s}} d y. $$

Using the fundamental theorem of calculus and  the relation $\nabla [|x|^\alpha]= \alpha x|x|^{\alpha-2}$,

$$\begin{align}&(1-s)\int_{\Omega \cap B_r(x)}\frac{(u(x)-u(y))}{|x-y|^{d+2s}} d y\\ & = -\int_0^1 dt (1-s)\int_{\Omega \cap B_r(x)}\frac{\nabla u(x+ t(y-x))\cdot (y-x)}{|x-y|^{d+2s}}dy\\&=  \int_0^1 dt\frac{ (1-s)}{d-2(1-s))}\int_{\Omega \cap B_r(x)}  \nabla u(x+ t(y-x))\cdot \nabla_y [|x-y|^{-d+2(1-s)}]dy \end{align}$$

Therefore my initial question could be resumed to computaion of

$$\lim_{s\to 1} (1-s)\int_{\Omega \cap B_r(x)} \nabla u(x+ t(y-x))\cdot \nabla_y [|x-y|^{-d+2(1-s)}]dy.$$

Any idea on to move further?

My feeling is the should be  a multiple factor of $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}(x)= \nabla u(x).n(x)$ where $n(x)$  is the normal derivative on $\partial \Omega$ at the point $x$. Don't be mind corrupted, I may have wrong expectation.

Comment: **1)** In the last integral of the second formula,  $t^{ 2s-1}$ is a typo for $t^{{\bf -}2s-1}$, isn't it? **2)**  If $u(x)$ is affine, say $u(y)=-y_1$  and $x=0$, the integrand in the first formula is $y_1|y|^{-d-2s}$ that is not locally integrable at $x$ for $s>1/2$ or am I wrong?

Comment: If you also assume $\nabla u(x)=0$, then I think you get 
$$L=-{\omega_d\over8}\Delta u(x) $$
where $\omega_d$ is the $d$-volume of the unit ball.

Comment: (as a consequence, $L$ should be infinite or undefined whenever $\nabla u(x)\neq0$ )

Comment: Thanks, for reacting. the functons $u(y) =y_1 $ is not bounded as I am only working with such functions.

Comment: @GuyFsone it is bounded if $\Omega$ is bounded and locally the integral still diverges.

Comment: @GuyFsone I think the situation is the one I wrote in comments above.  If you want nevertheless something like your last lines, maybe try $d+s$ instead of $d+2s$ as exponent in the integral.

Comment: If you put $d+s$ instead of $d+2s$ as exponent, then I think you get what you expected,
$$L=(\nabla u(x) \cdot n )\omega_{d-1},$$
the (outer) normal derivative times the $(d-1)$ volume of the unit $(d-1)$ ball.

Comment: Please can you show me that ?

Comment: Which one? For the  $(d+s)$ case,  you need a rescaling+limit argument, like in your firs part, so that the computation of the integral needs to be done only for the limit case, with $\Omega$=a half-space and $u$ linear; here you can also use symmetries. For the $(d+2s)$ case the computation it is analogous, but you need to assume $\nabla u(x)=0$, otherwise the integral is either undefined or infinite. Then the computation of the integral is reduced analogously by blow-up to the case of a a quadratic $u$ on a half-space; again you may use symmetries.